# Paginate order list by 15 items and sort by price ASC

Tags: magento2.3, sorting, pagination

I need to do sort by price and paginate by 15 items for order list history page, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize it properly, follow the 2 steps:

1, create a **afterGetOrders** plugin to **Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History**, in this plugin , check if $result->isLoaded(), if not, $result->setOrder('grand_total', 'desc') or 'asc' (you don't want to change query on loaded collection)

2, as the way pager is inserted in the layout in magento, it does not give you an opportunity to do DI as expected, so instead, to change pagination, we create a **beforeSetNameInLayout** plugin to **\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager**, and if parameter $name == 'sales.order.history.pager', we call $subject->setAvailableLimit([15 => 15, 20 => 20, ...])

Comment: In which file we can do those changes pls?

Comment: You would want to create a custom module and create the 2 plugins as I mentioned.
If you wanted to modify core magento files directly (strongly not recommended), then you will find the methods in the class files I mentioned

Comment: Thank you,Do you have an idea how to change text in toolbar amount only in order history page?